# Class that implements trait with annotated field loses annotation on trait field if annotation contains closure field

Tags: groovy, annotations, traits, groovyscriptengine

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
import java.lang.annotation.Retention
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface AnnotationWithClosure {
    Class closure() default { true }
}

trait TraitWithAnnotatedField {
    @AnnotationWithClosure(closure = {})
    String foo
    @AnnotationWithClosure()
    String bar
}

class Main implements TraitWithAnnotatedField {
    def printFields() {
        this.class.declaredFields.each {
            println "${it} is annotated ${it.isAnnotationPresent(AnnotationWithClosure.class)}"
        }
    }
}

new Main().printFields()
```

When I execute this script, in console I see following:

**private java.lang.String Main.TraitWithAnnotatedField__bar is annotated : true**
**private java.lang.String Main.TraitWithAnnotatedField__foo is annotated : false**

Can someone explain this behavior? How to correctly get annotations with closures from trait fields and process them in groovy?

```
$ groovy -version
Groovy Version: 2.4.12 JVM: 1.8.0_144 Vendor: Azul Systems, Inc. OS: Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behaviour of Groovy, sadly.

Annotating your trait with `@CompileStatic` solves the problem though.